# Updating TextBox After Execution of a Method Winforms

Tags: c#, sql-server, winforms

I'm making a C# app to resotre many .bak Files stored in a directory. It works fine now, but I have one problem I can't seem to resolve and would like your help.  The ExecuteNonQuery Takes a While to restore one .bak file and i want to update a textbox with a message everytime the ExecuteNonQuery  completes.

I tried to call the ExecuteNonQueryAsync but i get this Message :

> The connection does not take in charge MultipleActiveResultSets

My question is: How can I update The TextBox each time the executeNonQuery finishes?

Here is my code, please advise :

```
foreach (FileInfo file in Files)
        {
            string DbNamequery = "RESTORE FILELISTONLY FROM DISK = N'" + FolderBrowser.SelectedPath + @"\" + file.Name + "'" ;

            sqlform.ConSQL.PrepareQuery(DbNamequery);

            try
            {
              string DbName = sqlform.ConSQL.GetDataBaseName();
              string RestoreQuery = "RESTORE DATABASE [" + file.Name + "] FILE = N'" + DbName + "' FROM  DISK = N'" + FolderBrowser.SelectedPath + @"\" + file.Name;
                     RestoreQuery += "' WITH  FILE = 1,MOVE N'" + DbName + @"' TO N'C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL11.MSSQLSERVER\MSSQL\DATA\" + file.Name + ".mdf'";
                     RestoreQuery += ",MOVE N'" + DbName + @"_log' TO N'C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL11.MSSQLSERVER\MSSQL\DATA\" + file.Name + "_0.ldf',";
                     RestoreQuery += "NOUNLOAD,  STATS = 10";

                sqlform.ConSQL.PrepareQuery(RestoreQuery);

                sqlform.ConSQL.ExecuteQuery();

                ReportTextBox.Text += "Data Base : " + DbName + " Has been Restored With this Name :" + file.Name + " Successfully \r\n";

            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                ReportTextBox.Text += "Couldn't Resotre File " + file.Name + " Because of The following : \r\n" + ex.Message;
            }
        }
```

Definition for ExecuteQuery() :

```
  public async void ExecuteQuery()
    {
      int x = await  cmd.ExecuteNonQueryAsync();   
    }
```

When I execute The Query synchronously it works fine but the ReportTextbox doesn't get updated until the loop has ended.

Also this code is wrapped in a Click Button Event

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all you shouldn't have `async void` method rather return a `Task`

```
  public async Task<int> ExecuteQuery()
    {
      int x = await cmd.ExecuteNonQueryAsync(); 
      return x;  
    }
```

In your calling code, `await` the method call and update textbox, hopefully you want to update the textbox text only if the `RESTORE` operation succeeds

```
int result = await sqlform.ConSQL.ExecuteQuery();
if(result > 0) 
ReportTextBox.Text += "Data Base : " + DbName + " Has been Restored With this Name :" + file.Name + " Successfully \r\n";
```

Comment: Oh I see i never thought about returning a Task<Int> , so every Asyncronos Methode Sould return something that is Task Type ? , now it's updating my textbox however even if the query Executes well the result > 0 test always Fail ? i think my try catch would be enough to detect if the RESTORE operation succeeds  don't you think so ?? anyway Thanks man for your insight it really Helped